# I have registered MS Office 2011 for Mac and spelled the company name incorrectly, how do I change it?

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2011

I have registered MS Office 2011 for Mac and spelled the company name incorrectly.

Is there anyway of changing it, or do I have reinstall?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to open Word, select *Preferences » User Information*. Change your details there. I don't know if these settings apply to your whole Office installation though.

You could also change this company information in `/Users/<your-username>/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.office.plist`. You need the developer tools installed (for the Preference List editor). Find the key named `14\UserInfo\UserOrganization` and change the string there.

---

As usual with Microsoft Office products for Mac, they go their own way and it does not seem to be that easy to change the information. Microsoft has a more detailed description on how to [reset the Software License Registry information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2394111):

> 1. Quit all Microsoft applications.
> 2. Click on the Go in the top menu in Finder and choose Home.
> 3. Open Library.
> 4. Open Preferences.
> 5. Click to select com.microsoft.office.plist and drag it to Trash
>      (Don't empty the Trash before the new information is entered).
> 6. Open the Microsoft folder (**NOTE:** if you have Service Pack 2 Installed this will be in `~/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/Preferences/`).
> 7. Open Office 2011.
> 8. Click to select Office Registration Cache and OLE Registration
>      Database and drag it to  Trash (Don't empty the Trash before the new
>      information is entered).
> 9. Restart the Mac.
> 10. Launch Word/Excel/PowerPoint/Outlook and click Continue on the
>       first window.
> 11. Select Yes or No to the 2 questions on the next window and click
>       Continue.12.  Enter the correct user information on the next window.

Comment: Doesn't work its only for Word.  The plist file doesn't exist on my machine

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I can't find com.microsoft.office.plist anywhere on my mac

Comment: It should be automatically created under `/Users/your-user/Library/Preferences`. If it's not there, then that's probably nothing to worry about, just continue with the removal steps from Microsoft.